# CGRectIntersectsRect Not Working Properly

Tags: objective-c, collision-detection

After running this code and making the bullet pass the line, nothing appears in the debugger

```
//This is for the button that shoots the bullet
- (IBAction)shooterButton:(id)sender {
    [self mover:(id)sender];
    [self viewDidCollidee];
}

-(BOOL)viewsDoCollide {
    CGRect bulletFrame = _bullet.frame;
    CGRect lineFrame = _line.frame;
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(bulletFrame, lineFrame))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)viewDidCollidee {
    bool collisionDetector = [self viewsDoCollide];

    if (collisionDetector == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Collided!");
    }
}

- (void)mover:(id)sender {
    CGRect bulletFrame = _bullet.frame;
    CGRect lineFrame = _line.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(bulletFrame.origin.x + lineFrame.origin.x + 15, bulletFrame.origin.y, bulletFrame.size.width, bulletFrame.size.height);
        _bullet.frame= newFrame;
    }];
}
```

Where am I going wrong? I've checked many questions already answered about collision and I can't see it. Is there any other way to detect the collision? If not, where am I going wrong?

Edit: I took KirkSpaziani's suggestion but changed:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(bulletFrame.origin.x + lineFrame.origin.x + 15, bulletFrame.origin.y, bulletFrame.size.width, bulletFrame.size.height);
```

To:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(bulletFrame.origin.x + lineFrame.origin.x - 14, bulletFrame.origin.y, bulletFrame.size.width, bulletFrame.size.height);
```

Note, it is -14 instead of +15. But this way, the collision is detected even if the images haven't collided yet. How to I detect the collision when the collision actually takes place.

Comment: What values do `bulletFrame` and `lineFrame` have? Use the debugger!

Comment: @KurtRevis What do you mean? Both bullet and line are UIImageVIew properties that are weak and nonamatic if that's what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only checking if they collide when you fire the event

```
- (IBAction)shooterButton:(id)sender {
    [self mover:(id)sender];
    [self viewDidCollidee];
}
```

You probably want to call viewDidCollidee(sic) every frame.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(bulletFrame.origin.x + lineFrame.origin.x + 15, bulletFrame.origin.y, bulletFrame.size.width, bulletFrame.size.height);
    _bullet.frame= newFrame;
    [self viewDidCollidee];
}];
```

This is still probably not what you actually want, because you may pass through your object without a check if the velocity of the object takes it past the other object in between frames.

Comment: Draw a bounding rectangle from the previous position of the bullet to the current position for each frame.  You might check once and it'll look like this:  [ ] |, then next it'll look like this:  | [ ], so they never intersected on a single frame check.  Instead remember the previous position and do the intersect check like this: {[ ] | [ ]}, where {...} represents the actual rect your using.